# Encoding/Content-Type issue with Danish letters "æ"

Tags: java, http, character-encoding, httpresponse, content-type

I have an issue with encoding the Danish letters from the HTTP REST response.

When I call the REST service I am getting "bev�ge" which must be "bevæge", The Chrome browser encodes it and gives me the expected letters as "bevæge", but when I read the response from Java API's I am getting "bev�ge", can sombody help me to solve this issue, will be greatful,

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's very difficult to see what's wrong with your code, if you don't include the code with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a mismatch with your encoding

Consider

```
    String str = "bevæge";

    byte[] b = str.getBytes();

    try {
        System.out.println(new String (b, "US-ASCII"));
        System.out.println(new String (b, "UTF8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The output would be

```
bev��ge
bevæge
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like, if the string is transferred as ISO8859-1

Try Below::

```
String str = "bevæge";

byte[] b = str.getBytes();

try {
    System.out.println(new String (b, "ISO8859-1"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

willl ouput

bevæge

Answer (score 0):

In your HttpClient, try adding the following header:
Accept-charset: UTF-8